# get query via cursor stops the application

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am trying to read data from a database and my application stops.
I have this log:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
07-14 06:43:00.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2604):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
```

this is the method:

```
public Cursor getDetails(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {EMAIL,PASSWORD}, null, null, null, null, null);


    return cursor;

}
```

This is on the main activity:

```
cursor = handler.getDetails();
            email_by_user = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EMAIL));
```

any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are accessing data from `Cursor` object then you must have to position the `Cursor` object.

Actually you have to position `Cursor` to the first row before you try to access data from it.

Put the line

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

before the line

```
email_by_user = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EMAIL));
```

i.e. rewrite your activity code as

```
cursor = handler.getDetails();
if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    email_by_user = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EMAIL));
}
```